# How to make a function that take a callback which can take multiple arguments

Tags: typescript

I'm developing a project in typescript and want to make a function, in which that function will take a single argument with type of callback, but the callback can have multiple arguments.

I have tried looking in the typescript issue for similiar use case [1](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4338#issuecomment-138268291), but I got an error of "TS2394: This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature."

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4338#issuecomment-138268291

```js
export interface Subscription {
  (): void
}
export interface xsSubscription {
  unsubscribe(): void
}

const createSubscription = () => {
  return {
    unsubscribe() {}
  }
}

type SyncMethod0 = (callback: () => void) => Subscription
type SyncMethod1<T1> = (callback: (data: T1) => void) => Subscription
type SyncMethod2<T1, T2> = (callback: (data1: T1, data2: T2) => void) => Subscription
type SyncMethod3<T1, T2, T3> = (callback: (data1: T1, data2: T2, data3: T3) => void) => Subscription

// The problem are in the next line, if I comment line 10 the problem are gone
function fromSync(method: SyncMethod0): (method: SyncMethod0) => xsSubscription
function fromSync<T1>(method: SyncMethod1<T1>): (method: SyncMethod1<T1>) => xsSubscription
function fromSync<T1, T2>(method: SyncMethod2<T1, T2>): (method: SyncMethod2<T1, T2>) => xsSubscription
function fromSync<T1, T2, T3>(method: SyncMethod3<T1, T2, T3>): (method: SyncMethod3<T1, T2, T3>) => xsSubscription
function fromSync(method: any) {
  let subscription: Subscription

  // For dummy data
  return createSubscription()

  // The real code are here, it will create an Observable (from xstreamjs)
  // return xs.create({
  //   start(listener) {
  //     subscription = method((...data) => {
  //       listener.next(...data);
  //     });
  //   },
  //   stop() {
  //     subscription();
  //   }
  // });
}
```

EDIT: Updated code example

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZQFcAjAZ2ygTBgQiTgG8BYAKDjgAoBKALjgDcICACasAvq1CRYiFGiy44IUkTIUqNOo1btCSUiXKViwbn0EjxrVtjql4FYJlSqjG2vQC8nLnE8A+bTY4KGAYQih6ZmDdfUN1E25GCWCUlNYYAE8wPHxMpGwAWTCACwhhAAY-TmxMABs64hwAaz4kgIEhYV8O13VqDwzs3Pyi0vKARgAeABUJwO8OWoam7FbOYWdMPjmewItuv0C+ygG6IZyCUeKYMuEAJlmJgBo4GfuFmvrGlrbNmEwEx2Lzg-0w9x29z2nRE0JO7nOLCylzyBRudwAzE9Xu8cRjPktvqt1hwwUC3iCwRC3vdXmCMTsMdCDnD4qdNEhrCwAPTct4lPBgKAQYh1YAAWzgmFCsjgtzwSFA8DqyGArwQ6DgAEk4LZxeLgCg4CrFXAJlV5XAhSKxZLpXgAOZ0YCsdB6bAcuDoYXi1HYDgG27lPh+9HlCq8TiBu4h67jSrQ5Tws6clhugqe70QX2jJ7+APx2No+PTOb+SMFoPCItjKul+aJlRshGp9Mejxen1+7E0-PR4NXYtVx5zHEfCv96uD2t3Ecg97lo5KJtqdmDNPuzNd3Ojml4vuF6dh4RY3e4t74ieH0Px0-z2kXxcdJPNlOuzcdrM5gqVmNSpCZL40TsGK8AGKuLYhq+HJcuwvJwAAYtAoKEPqmSglsOghGEET0I4zjAMmHLcLBcDwTMArYfUurlHg9pwAKoTqvAADuCANLqoQEf+cAAPJkGg-CYKKeAcF+y4wFx4oAFakFwWHwaE4SRMuAB0+GoBwwFkXy7D2NKMAcCq9iGmgQEKbp7BwOBbgptUk4cBwqnOWC0LafBVlWcZqCKlAqmKiAhnOaprkANwWZ5cBiFw4XBB5UXPBFekwBAYBJO5ll6dBHjcLFcGWSk+VRTF4hAA) is a link to typescript playground.

Comment: Please consider editing the code to constitute a [mcve], as currently I cannot reproduce your error and the code has other errors when I drop it into an [IDE](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/Q).  Since TypeScript 3.0 I would probably implement this with rest tuples and not overloads, but without a reproducible issue I don't know what your problem is.

Comment: For example, [rest tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZQFcAjAZ2ygTBgQiTgG8BYAKDjgAoBKALjgDcICACYBuVgF9WrGAE8wefLKTYAssBgALCMIA8AFTihUSYaTiYksgNoBdAHxwAvJ1btsmADafiOANZ8HAB0IcKYMJh8+lzOjoIirDFOjkRkFFQ0dOIsrMLA2J6YUHjohCqZ9OhQEAC2SioGRiAmZhZWdvYcbnA1GtrCfPVqfToG9omBvVo6g8rD03r69kkpJOSU1LRI2UA)

Comment: Hi @jcalz thank you for commenting, I have updated my code example to show only my problem. And for your rest tuple solution, will it work for parameter with different type? or is it for 1 type only?